# How to connect to an oracle database from JSP file

Tags: java, html, oracle

I have an oracle database I need to connect a JSP file to my oracle database.  I am very new to JSP if possible please tell me if there are any dependencies I need to download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 

<html> 
<head> 
<title>Connection with Oracle database</title> 
</head> 
<body>
<h1>Connection status </h1>
<% 
try {
/* Create string of connection url within specified format with machine name, 
port number and database name. Here machine name id localhost and 
database name is usermaster. */ 
String connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle""; 

// declare a connection by using Connection interface 
Connection connection = null; 

// Load JBBC driver "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance(); 

/* Create a connection by using getConnection() method that takes parameters of 
string type connection url, user name and password to connect to database. */ 
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");

// check weather connection is established or not by isClosed() method 
if(!connection.isClosed())
%>
<font size="+3" color="green"></b>
<% 
out.println("Successfully connected to " + "Oracle");
connection.close();
}
catch(Exception ex){
%>
</font>
<font size="+3" color="red"></b>
<%
out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
}
%>
</font>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the jsp file is an html file that is rendered in the server so you can add server code to add information in the final HTML page that you send to the browser.

However, you shouldn't manage the connection to the database inside the jsp file. You should configure it in your java classes (database drivers, jdbc connection, thread pool to connect, prepared statements.. etc, etc)and then you can query the database directly form you jsp in you want

Comment: "you can't manage the connection to the database inside the jsp file" This is not correct. You can connect to database from JSP file but it's not advisable.